# Is the movie Interstella 5555 considered "sci-fi"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the movie allowed here?  Is it considered more as a movie? Or is it considered sci-fi.  I don't really want to gather more downvotes; I just want to know whether or not it's within the scope of the faq.

Comment: Off-topic questions should **not** be downvoted anyway. If a question is not on-topic it should be voted to close. Downvotes are for bad questions (and answers). Regardless; Insterstella is **massively** on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, that movie is science fiction - or at least SFF enough to be within the scope of the FAQ. No guarantee that you won't still get downvoted. Some people are offended by any attempt to take movies they don't like seriously.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how that movie could be interpreted as **not** science fiction.

Let's put it this way: *My Little Pony* is on topic here.  A movie about a group of alien musicians being kidnapped and held prisoner on Earth is *certainly* going to be on topic!

By all means, please ask!

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly on-topic on [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/). The accepted answer indicates that it is on-topic here as well, so you're welcome to ask here or there, though you [should not ask on both sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073).

Take into consideration that [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) will probably be a better fit, since Anime is the specific purpose of that site. Being a moderator there, I can say that this question would be most welcome over there. We're new in the SE network, but we're building a solid group of 'experts', so you'll definitely find some good answers there.

Check it out :D

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstella_5555:_The_5tory_of_the_5ecret_5tar_5ystem), I would vote yes. But if you're really concerned, you could try the [TV & Movies StackExchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) where it would definitely be on-topic.

Comment: I dunno. Is it considered a movie? Just because it's a few million still frames stiched together with synchronous audio tracks, doesn't necessarily make it a film.

Comment: Nuuu, _we_ should be leeching questions from _them_!  (Provided they're on topic, of course)  (^_—)

Comment: @JohnO: It's a film. Being made in Japan doesn't change that,

Comment: @JohnO Lack of dialog or spoken parts does not disqualify something as a film.  Just ask Charlie Chaplin fans :P  Interstella 5555 has a fairly detailed plot, and even manages some character development, which, imo, is all the more impressive for the lack of dialog.

Comment: @JohnO: FWIW, *I* found that funny. :-)