# How should I distinguish between SciFi.SE and Anime.SE?

Tags: discussion, anime, site-rec

I'm asking this, because I thought of a question, but I'm afraid to ask because I"m not sure if it's the right fit.

I was planning to ask a question about Devil May Cry, which is not only a video game, but used to be a manga as well, but was related to something specific to the characters within the game.

For those who haven't played it, it's basically about two guys who are demon + angel offspring, called Nephilim, and a bunch of other stuff.

But I'm not sure, is this more suited to Anime.SE, due to it's manga-y nature? or is it somewhat more suited to here, not only due to it's video game-y nature, but it's about demons and angels (even the page theme for Sci.SE suggests that)?

But overall, I'm trying to ask, how should I differentiate whether or not X is a better fit for SciFi.SE or Anime.SE?

Comment: I'm going to be (potentially) annoying and add even more confusion, since there's also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ that you could potentially post your question on. It all depends on what the question is, and while you seem to be looking for general guidelines, a concrete example to refer to may be helpful - could you include the question you want to ask in this one?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think the established concensus is that questions related to video game lore/backstory belong in SciFi.SE (assuming they're scifi/fantasy, of course), not in Gaming.SE.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist While the FAQ/policy doesn't outright forbid story-based questions at gaming.stackexchange, my questions regarding those have gone pretty much ignored. They seem pretty focused on gameplay elements and mechanics.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Read Arqade's FAQ.  They allow "Plot and characters in games" questions.

Comment: @Keen Yes, but there appears to be a caveat: that the questions are covered by [canon materials](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2293/8096).

Comment: There's an overlap. If your question is on-topic on both, pick one. See [How do we handle conflicts with the Anime and Movies sites?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you should read the FAQ for the three sites ([Anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/faq), [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)).
After having done so, you may come to the conclusion that the question would only be welcome in one of them, in which case you have your answer.
However, you can come to the conclusion that it would be welcome in two/all of them. It's no surprise: **there's bound to be some overlapping** (especially between SF&F and Anime). So it comes down to 2 questions:

- Where do you think the question will **help more people**?
- Where do you think your question will **get better answers**?

I understand that some people may worry about the fact that Anime is still on beta, meaning there is a risk of losing good Q/A if we were to closed. However, I would like to point out that our **stats have been growing** steadily ever since we came out of private beta. Plus, our main focus there is (obviously) **anime and manga**, meaning that the **community being built is 'specialized' in those fields**. Having said that, it is my opinion that **any question regarding anime/manga is a better fit for Anime**. On that note, I encourage you to ask your Devil May Cry question over there.
Since this question in particular pertains to Devil May Cry, I'd also like to point out that we allow **story-related** questions about anime-style and anime-based games (see [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/415/49) for more info). Mechanics and gameplay belong, of course, to Arqade.
Also, be careful with [cross-site posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/208518).

There are also some examples of (similar) questions that have been asked both here and at Anime:

- [Did Walter become Millennium's servant by choice?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24805/6365) (here)
- [Did Walter become Millennium's servant by choice?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2055/49) (at Anime)
- [Suggested starting place for Ghost in the Shell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/20628/6365) (here)
- [In what order should I watch the Ghost in the Shell series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2922/49) (at Anime)

From those you can draw some conclusions, and hopefully I've been helpful.
Let me me finish by saying, [once again](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2628/6365), that your anime questions are always welcome at [Anime](http://anime.stackexchange.com)!

---

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that we've been promoting an event called [Flavor Day](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/what-flavors-would-you-like-to-see-for-our-weekly-flavor-days), on which we select a 'flavor' (or two) each week (on Saturdays) and encourage people to ask questions about it/them. Incidentally, this week's flavor (Saturday May 4th) is "games" and "sports". So questions about DMC will be a perfect fit there!

Comment: I'd add that in the past when beta sites were closed the SE team provided bulk migration of questions to other sites when appropriate.  ex astronomy.SE was mostly migrated to physics.SE (with a smaller chunk to photo.SE) as was theoreticalPhysics.SE (with one the programing sites took the quantum computing questions).  If Anime.SE were to fail it's reasonable to assume that scifi anime questions would be mass migrated to SciFi.SE; so there's no reason to worry about losing content.

Comment: Nice, thanks for that bit of info!